# Equation for a cone that is "upside down"?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

The equation of a cone who was its tip on the xy plane is $x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}$. How can I describe a cone whose base is on the xy plane, and tip on a point on the z-axis, i.e. the cone $x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}$ but upside down?

Comment: Replace $z$ by $z-x_0$. For the cone to have a base and tip instead of being infinite you will also need to specify a range of values for $z$.

Comment: $x^2+y^2 = (a-z)^2$ if $(0,0,a)$ is the vertex of the cone. If the base of the cone is in $XY$ plane then add $0 \leq z \leq a$. Also note that $x^2+y^2 = z^2$ represent two cones, one above $XY$ plane and one below. Same with $x^2+y^2 = (a-z)^2$, one above $z=a$ and one below.

Comment: Thank you so much! For a cone having a height H i suppose it would be $x^{2}+y^{2}=(z-H)^{2}$, but if I also want the cone to have a radius of R, how would I incorporate that into the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a right circular cone having height $H$, radius $R$ on the $z = 0$ plane, and apex at $z = H$:
$$\left( x^2 + y^2 \right) \left( \frac{H}{R} \right)^2 = \left( z - H \right)^2, \quad 0 \le z \le H$$
i.e.
$$\left( x^2 + y^2 \right) \left( \frac{H}{R} \right)^2 - \left( z - H \right)^2 = 0, \quad 0 \le z \le H$$
or as a function $z = f(x, y)$ (solving above for $z$),
$$z = H \left( 1 - \sqrt{\frac{ x^2 + y^2 }{R^2}} \right), \quad x^2 + y^2 \le R^2$$

Comment: Thanks so much! How did you think when you put the factor $(H/R)^{2}$, i.e. why does one multiply by that?

Comment: @Pi314 It's a more general kind of cone than you asked about. The equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ gives a cone with a $90$ degree opening angle. If you just write $z-H$ instead of $z$, you will get the same shape of cone. By introducing another factor you can get a cone whose opening angle is narrower or wider.

Comment: @Pi314: Exactly like David K wrote.  The equation $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ can be written as $r^2 = z^2$ in cylindrical coordinates ($(r, \theta, z)$), i.e. $\lvert z \rvert = r$.  For the positive cone only, $z \ge 0$, so $z = r$.  If we want $z$ be $H$ when the radius is $R$, and we only consider $z \ge 0$, then we use $r H/R = z$, or $r^2 (H/R)^2 = z^2$, and back in Cartesian coordinates, $(x^2 + y^2)(H/R)^2 = z^2$.  To invert the cone, $(x^2 + y^2)(H/R)^2 = (H - z)^2 = (z - H)^2$.

Comment: @Glörbo Thank you! When I solve for z in the above equation i get $$z = H \left( 1 + \sqrt{\frac{ x^2 + y^2 }{R^2}} \right), \quad x^2 + y^2 \le R^2$$ and not a minus sign as you got?

Comment: @Pi314: $$(x^2 + y^2)\left(\frac{H}{R}\right)^2 = (z - H)^2$$has two roots: $$z = H \pm H \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{R^2}}$$You seem to have picked the wrong root: see how the $+$ defines the cone at $H \le z \le 2H$, and the $-$ defines a cone at $0 \le z \le H$?  Perhaps the fact that $(H - z)^2 = (z - H)^2$ tripped you?

Comment: @Glärbo, I see. Thank you again, you have been really helpful!